# Test class error while insert a record

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm trying to insert a record under Account using test class as follows

```
List< Account> c = new List <Account>(NameLocal='test44',Name='testprimary',Industry='Aerospace');
insert c;
```

Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ',' at line 10 column 61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting mixed up with the List and the Account. You should be creating the List first and then adding the Account into it as shown here:

```
List< Account> accounts = new List <Account>();
accounts.add(new Account(NameLocal='test44',Name='testprimary',Industry='Aerospace'));
insert accounts;
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do it without the List you could do:

```
Account account = new Account(NameLocal='test44',Name='testprimary',Industry='Aerospace');
insert account;
```

Comment: here is process i'm doing.
  private static Opportunity so1;
  private static Opportunity so2;

  // set up our data for each test method
  static {
          
     Account account = new Account(NameLocal='test44',Name='testprimary',Industry='Aerospace');
insert account;
    
    so1 = new Opportunity(name='test1',Account=account.id,CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',CloseDate='08/01/2014',StageName='Demo');
    so2 = new Opportunity(name='test2',Account=account.id,CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',CloseDate='08/01/2014',StageName='Demo');
    
    insert new List<Opportunity>{so1,so2};
    
  }

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Invalid initial expression type for field Account, expecting: SOBJECT:Account (or single row query result of that type) at line 13 column 48

Comment: Hi @Sindoora. That appears to be a different issue to your original question. Can you please create a new question. I cant tell which line is line 13, where the error is happening.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @ BarCotter.Account=account.id

Comment: Try AccountId = account.id